# Presto Or Trino, How to parse date with out separator

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Date is in format as YYYYMMDD eg 20200125= 20200 Jan 25. No Separator found in data.
How to cast to date time as YY-MM-DD format

```
select date_parse( mydate, 'YYYYMMDD') as castDate
```

**SQL Error [7]**: Query failed (#20220504_161754_00322_m75nu): Invalid format: "20200125"

```
date_parse( mydate, '%Y%m%d') as castDate
```

**SQL Error [7]**: Query failed (#20220504_161820_00323_m75nu): Invalid format: "MISSING"

Answer (score 3):

`select date_parse('20200125', '%Y%m%d')` works fine for me:

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2020-01-25 00:00:00.000 |

It seems that some dates are not in the provided format (i.e. not dates at all like `"MISSING"`). You can wrap your parse expression into `try` to see which ones:

```sql
select castDate
from table
where try(date_parse(castDate, '%Y%m%d')) is NULL
limit 5
```

Comment: My BAD.. Nice Catch !!:-)